# Google API Batch Request - .NET REST Call Gives error

Tags: rest, google-api, restsharp

I am having .NET code to call the google api in batch request for getting the message details for multiple Ids. The request I am creating, when run through postman it works perfectly but when run this console app it gives me the `Response Status code = 0` and Error `Specified value has invalid CRLF characters.\r\nParameter name: value`

Can someone please look into this and help me ... I have searched almost everything now but could not get any solution.

Here is my code --

```
            var baseUrl = "/gmail/v1/users/" + _accountID + "/messages/";

            RestClient client = null;
            RestRequest request = null;
            StringBuilder sbBody = null;
            for (int j = 0; j < _messageId.Count; j++)
            {
                msgCount++;
                if (msgCount == 1)
                {
                    boundary = "testing_batch";
                    sbBody = new StringBuilder();
                    client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com/batch/");
                    request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

                    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"");
                    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                }

                sbBody.Append(string.Format("--{0}\n", boundary));
                sbBody.Append("Content-Type: application/http\n\n");
                sbBody.Append(string.Format("GET {0}{1}\n\n", baseUrl, _messageId[j]));

                if (msgCount == 1)
                    sbBody.Append(string.Format("--{0}--", boundary));

                if (msgCount == 1)
                {
                    msgCount = 0;
                    //request.AddBody(sbBody.ToString());
                    request.AddHeader("RequestBody", sbBody.ToString());
                    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {

                            //Do nothing for now

                    }
                    else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: So in Postman you add the whole request to a header???

Comment: Use Fiddler to trace the request you make using your code and using Postman, it will be obvious where the difference is.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev In postman I am adding the request body in body and rest of the header parameters in headers

Comment: Still try Fiddler to see the difference.